# How to use vuex modules in vue 3

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I have a vue 3 (Javascript) project. Trying to split my vuex store to modules but I keep getting the error `[vuex] unknown getter: loginToken`. As far as I understand the only [major] change with `vuex 4.0.0-beta` is the import statement. How one uses modules should still be the same?

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import * as auth from "./modules/auth";

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    auth,
  },
  state: {
    ....
  },
  getters: {
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    ...
  }
})
```

**store/modules/auth.js**

```
import firebase from "./../../firebase";

const state = {
  loginToken: null,
}

const getters = {
  loginToken({ loginToken }) {
    return loginToken;
  },
}

const mutations = {
  loginToken(state, token) {
    if(token) {
      state.loginToken = token;
    } else {
      state.loginToken = null;
    }
  }
}

const actions = {
  login(context, request) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(request.email, request.password)
        .then(({ user }) => {
          context.dispatch("getUserProfile", user.uid).then(() => {
            context.commit("loginToken", user.uid);
            resolve(user.uid);
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
        reject(error)
      });
    })
  }
}

export default { state, getters, mutations, actions }
```

Page.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
        <ion-button @click="gotoProfile" v-if="loginToken">Profile</ion-button>
        <ion-button @click="logout" v-if="loginToken">Logout</ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-buttons>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title class="logo" @click="gotoHome">{{ name }} </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  ....
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['loginToken']),
  },
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a code example of how you are using the getters?

Comment: did you try out `...mapGetters(['auth/loginToken']),`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim when I use `auth/loginToken` I get a warning now. `Property "loginToken" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. ` how do I use loginToken?

Comment: For me this solution doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516327/vue-3-how-to-use-vuex-modules#new-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imports in Vue.js 3 need to be like this:

```
 import auth from "./modules/auth";
```

but you have it as:

```
 import * as auth from "./modules/auth";
```